# How to transform raw data to fixed-frequency time series?

Tags: time-series, pandas, feature-extraction, feature-construction, dataframe

How to transform raw data to fixed-frequency time series?

For example I have the following raw data in DataFrame

```
                       A    B
2017-01-01 00:01:01    0    100
2017-01-01 00:01:10    1    200
2017-01-01 00:01:16    2    300
2017-01-01 00:02:35    3    100
2017-01-01 00:02:40    4    100
```

I'd like to transform it into a time series:

1. 1 minute frequency
2. column A should have sum of values in time interval
3. column B should have mean of values in time interval
4. possibly other functions over other columns

Note: Raw data is not periodic.

Transformed data should be:

```
                       A    B
2017-01-01 00:01:00    3    200
2017-01-01 00:02:00    7    100
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of effect can be achieved with 
[`pandas.DataFrame.resample()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) combined with [`Resampler.aggregate()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) like:

#### Code:

```
df.resample("1Min").agg({'A': sum, 'B': np.mean})
```

#### Test code:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
                           A    B
    2017-01-01T00:01:01    0    100
    2017-01-01T00:01:10    1    200
    2017-01-01T00:01:16    2    300
    2017-01-01T00:02:35    3    100
    2017-01-01T00:02:40    4    100"""),
                  header=1, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)

print(df)    
print(df.resample("1Min").agg({'A': sum, 'B': np.mean}))
```

#### Results:

```
                     A    B
2017-01-01 00:01:01  0  100
2017-01-01 00:01:10  1  200
2017-01-01 00:01:16  2  300
2017-01-01 00:02:35  3  100
2017-01-01 00:02:40  4  100

                     A    B
2017-01-01 00:01:00  3  200
2017-01-01 00:02:00  7  100
```